# I try to create a next.js webapp with vercel, but when i try to run vercel dev on cmd, it gave me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

```
vercel dev
Vercel CLI 28.5.3
> Creating initial build
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at cp.emit (C:\Users\IsWei\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vercel\node_modules\@vercel\build-utils\dist\index.js:17051:29)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd.exe',
  path: 'cmd.exe',
  spawnargs: [ '/C', 'yarn run dev' ]
}

Node.js v19.1.0
Error: Builder exited with 1 before sending build result
```

I have run npm install -g vercel and when I try to run vercel dev on cmd, it gave me this error, I have on windows 10 64bit, i already check my environment veraible, here is what i did

added C:\Windows\System32\ and C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe to both of the top and bottom environment variable Path, anyone help?

I also tried
yarn cache clean
yarn
yarn start

What I also did is to reinstall node, again it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure the "right way" to do it for a whole day,
what I ended up doing is creating a file named 'cmd.exe'.
I ran this command in cmd:

```
type "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" > cmd.exe
```